# Python Knapsack greedy

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, knapsack-problem

Given a dictionary of cows and their weight:

```
cows = {'Betsy': 9, 'Oreo': 6, 'Herman': 7, 'Florence': 2, 'Maggie': 3, 'Moo Moo': 3, 'Milkshake': 2, 'Lola': 2, 'Millie': 5, 'Henrietta': 9}
```

I want to get a list of lists to move all cows, each nested list of cow's a total weight <= 10, hence to first two trips will have just Betsy and Henrietta:

The answer for GREEDY COW TRANSPORT:

```
[['Betsy'], ['Henrietta'], ['Herman', 'Maggie'], ['Oreo', 'Moo Moo'], ['Millie', 'Florence', 'Milkshake'], ['Lola']]
```

Here is my code that took too long in a net grader:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
    train = []
    cart = [] 

# get tuples from dictionary key ordered by value high to low
    CowTupleList = sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

# put cow names in list order high to low to loop over
    names = []
    for i in range(len(cows)):
        names.append(CowTupleList[i][0])
    train = []
    while sum(cows.values()) > 0:
        cart = []
        total = 0

        for cow in names:
            if cows[cow] != 0 and cows[cow] + total <=limit:
                cart.append(cow)
                total += cows[cow]
                cows[cow] = 0
        train.append(cart)
    return train
```

This took too much time for the online grader, so I failed. Can this be done in only a few lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sort the cows, but you don't take advantage of the fact that they're sorted.  Instead of iterating over the cows multiple times (which leads to \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ time w.r.t. the number of cows), iterate over the sorted list once.

Unfortunately, I can't think of an easy way to do this using Python's built-in data structures.  However, if we assume that `CowTupleList` is some list-like datastructure that has \$\mathcal{O}(\log{n})\$ or better performance for all operations (including `del`), then we can use binary search to find the largest cow that will fit in a cart's remaining capacity:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
  # Sort cows from largest to smallest
  CowTupleList = sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

  while CowTupleList:
    # Add first (largest) cow to a new cart
    name,weight = CowTupleList[0]
    cart = [name]
    remaining_capacity = limit - weight

    # Remove first cow from list
    del CowTupleList[0]

    # Find largest remaining cow that fits in remaining capacity (if any)
    idx = find_largest_fitting(CowTupleList, remaining_capacity)
    while idx is not None:
      # Add the cow at idx to the cart
      name,weight = CowTupleList[idx]
      cart.append(name)
      remaining_capacity -= weight

      # Remove cow at idx from list
      del CowTupleList[idx]

      # Find largest remaining cow that fits (if any)
      idx = find_largest_fitting(CowTupleList, remaining_capacity)

    # No more cows fit => yield the cart
    yield cart
```

Assuming `find_largest_fitting` is implemented as a binary search over `CowTupleList` (and an appropriate data structure is chosen for `CowTupleList`), this should take \$\mathcal{O}(n\log{n})\$ time.  If linear search is used for `find_largest_fitting` and/or Python's build-in list type is used for `CowTupleList` (so that `del` operates in \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$), then this algorithm will operate in \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ time.

Comment: BINGO! Thank you nathan, yeild statements, another way...

Comment: BUT WAIT, you MIGHT fit a very light cow further down the list. Dont you have to check the entire list each time? That would be VERY greedy otherwise.  Greedy is what we did (without knowing it) when choosing the words from a hand in scrabble, ONLY you didn't have to delete a word once it was chosen.... grrrrrrrr

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, of course.  Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Although about checking the entire list ... you are only interested in the portion of the list that has cows that are no heaver than the remaining capacity.  So I suppose you could use a binary search to find the largest cow that fits?

Comment: Thanks so much Nat, YOURS was the major DUH!! moment with the <name, weight in tuples> ...

Comment: I updated the answer to use a binary search.  And now that I think of it, you should be able to iterate through the list once for each cart, since any cow that remains to be added must be further down in the list than what has been examined so far.  I don't have time to code this up at the moment, but perhaps I will in a bit.

Comment: 30 cows takes 100 times longer than 10, still only 1/1000 sec, but keen to learn for large applications. For large numbers and normal distribution alternately popping max and min from the list would work? Brute force partitions for 30 cows is 30th Bell's number ~ 10^24

Comment: The problem with popping from the end of the list is that a larger cow might fit.  So it's not really greedy.  But you could improve successive binary searches for the same cart by restricting the search to the portion of the list after the last cow that was added.  E.g., add a paremeter to `find_largest_fitting` that is the index at which to start the search.

Comment: Also, note that you won't see much (if any) improvement in performance without using an appropriate data structure.  `del` on Python's built-in list type is O(n) anyway, so the algorithm will be O(n^2) regardless, as long as you're using Python's builtin list type.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I got so far:

```
def greedy_cow_transport(cows,limit=10):
    train = []
    while sum(cows.values()) > 0:
        cart = []
        total = 0
        for cow, value in sorted(cows.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True):
            if cows[cow] != 0 and value + total <= limit:
                cart.append(cow)
                total += value
                cows[cow] = 0
        train.append(cart)
    return train
```

For the dictionary:

```
  cows = {'Betsy': 9,
 'Florence': 2,
 'Henrietta': 9,
 'Herman': 7,
 'Lola': 2,
 'Maggie': 3,
 'Milkshake': 2,
 'Millie': 5,
 'Moo Moo': 3,
 'Oreo': 6}
```

We get:

```
[['Betsy'],
 ['Henrietta'],
 ['Herman', 'Maggie'],
 ['Oreo', 'Moo Moo'],
 ['Millie', 'Milkshake', 'Lola'],
 ['Florence']]
```

Although, I have mutated the original dictionary which we're not supposed to do.

Comment: You can always create a copy of the original dictionary and mutate the copy.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give it a shot too.

I wrote various iterations of the code for this problem and the one I'm the most happy about (and that is easy to read and understand) is the following where I use a `while`-loop but start the counter at one less than the length and decrease the value each time in order to not go through the list of cows more than once.

```
def greedy_cow_transport_third_iteration(cows, limit=10):
trips, available = [], limit
# Make a list of cows, sort by weight in ascending fashion (lightest first)
cows = sorted([(weight, name) for name, weight in cows.items()])
while cows:                     # Loop through available cows
    trips.append([cows[-1][1]]) # Allocate heaviest cow on a new trip
    available -= cows[-1][0]    # Adjust available weight accordingly
    cows.remove(cows[-1])       # Remove this cow from future loops
    i = len(cows) - 1           # Reset index
    while i >= 0:               # Loop back through all remaiing cows
        if available > 0 and cows[i][0] <= available:
            trips[-1].append(cows[i][1])  # Allocate this cow!
            available -= cows[i][0]       # adjust available weight
            cows.remove(cows[i])          # Remove it from future loops
        i -= 1                  # Avoid infinite loops
    available = limit           # Reset available weight for next trip
return trips                    # Returns solution
```

I hope that helps somehow.

Comment: Each and every answer on Code Review should contain an insightful comment about the code provided. This is an alternative implementation without reviewing the code provided. Either provide a review or your answer isn't up to par.

Comment: Afar from that, welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, and thanks :)
I can also delete my reply altogether if that's for the better.